# Python requests library for oauth token

Tags: python, python-requests

So i was following the guide for getting a OAUTH token from `https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/`
I tried doing a python requests library of the above equivalent code but i got response 400 from the server. May I know where i am going wrong?

```
import requests
import json
import clientidandsecret


headers ={"Authorization": "Basic " + clientidandsecret.C_ID +":" +clientidandsecret.C_SECRET}
form = {"form":{"grant_type" :"client_credentials"}, "json":"true"}
result = requests.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", headers=headers, data=form)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable form is a Dict, if you want to use the parameter data in requests it needs to be a string, this will fix it:

```
import json
...
result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(form))
```

Or even better:

```
result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=form)
```

Comment: Thanks, now i am trying to figure out why its giving me response 415 despite following the instructions.

Comment: Double check the parameters you are sending, especially in the headers. Maybe send headers['Content-Type']  = 'application/json'.